# How can i be generic my title bar?

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a title bar one of my project and i want to use  my all screen.I think that i can do be a general( means i want a something and i will call everywhere like a style tag or theme tag) i have no idea.What can i use for?

My title bar is here:

```
RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="44dip"
            android:layout_width="320dip"
            android:background="@drawable/merhaba_header_320_44dip">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="32dip"
            android:layout_width="121dip"
            android:background="@drawable/merhaba_logo_121_32dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        </ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_width="64dip"
            android:background="@drawable/merhaba_btn_nedir_64_30dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is your question, how to apply that to all your activity's views?

Comment: i want to write one time like a style and i want to call all xml views like a @style.i think it can be doing but i dont know true tag name

Answer (score 0):

Hi DuyguK are you asking for a way to have a title bar that you can apply as a theme or something to all the activities in your app?

If that's so, I would recommend you to do the following.
First define a style in your res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">44dip</item>
        //whatever item you want/need to edit for your custom title bar
    </style>
</resources>
```

This allows you to have a theme that is applyable to your whole app. To do this you need to go to your AndroidManifest.xml file an inside the application tag add the following:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

The android:theme tells the app to use the theme named "MyTheme" that can be found in the res/values/styles.xml file in your project.
That way you can apply correctly your custom title bar to all your activities. 
Hope this answers your question if not, please specify!

An additional recommendation is to take a look at the ActionBarCompat project that comes with the samples in Android SDKs. The Android Developers page shows the project:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html

It has the advantage of being compatible with pre-API11 devices, is applied as a theme to your app and it is being used by lots of apps available in the store.
If you have any questions/trouble with it please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

create your own style which can ofcourse extend from existing from an existing theme. 
change the windowNoTitle to true.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="noTitleBarStyle" parent="android:Theme.Black">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/darkGrey</item>   
<item name="android:colorForeground">#ff3333</item> 
</style></resources>
```